# Difference between two tables by faster sql

Tags: sql, difference

I have two same tables which stores data around 4 millions. one table stores data on run time and another one stores data from the beginning. I want fast sql query which gives me difference between these tables. This tables does not have any primary key. I have tried with not exists but it takes very long time. Any suggestion?

Comment: What type of server?

Comment: depending on your setup it may not be possible to do this fast.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `except`...

```
--Only in TableA
select * from TableA
except
select * from TableB

--Only in TableB
select * from TableB
except
select * from TableA
```